# What is a good book/lecture notes that covers Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics and includes a lot of numerical computation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism

I am looking for a book or lecture notes that doesn't just describe the theory of Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics, but places strong emphasis on dealing with these topics computationally. Any computational physics book or lecture notes that I come across seems to be either a very basic introduction to standard numerical methods, or else focuses on very elementary physics.

So does anyone know any resource that may be of use? I would not normally ask for a resource recommendation on stackexchange sites but I have had no luck after lots of searching the net.

Comment: Goldstein "Classical Mechanics" is the standard one.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco: What numerical computations are in Goldstein? While I haven't looked at it in a looong time, I don't recollect any numerical problems in the text.

Comment: Ooops, I might have misinterpreted the word "computation": I meant "calculations" while I now realise that the question might mean "computer computations". In that case ignore my comment (I will delete it if so).

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Moreover, if I would have suggested Goldstein 20 years ago, I think that nowadays there are much better books, e.g. Scheck or Straumann (in German). They are not computationally oriented, though.

Comment: [Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/sicm/book-Z-H-4.html#%_toc_start)